# How to select a .list-cell, in javaFX CSS

Tags: css, javafx

Can somebody tell me, how I can style 1 ListView's, list-cells ?

I have two ListViews. one with id="#one", and id="#two".

Now I want to style the list-cells of each ListView differently.

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: rgba(16, 27, 49, 0.8);
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

This is my ".list-cell" that covers all list-cells. But I do not want that.

This is what I tried:

```
#one.list-view.list-cell
#one.list-view > list-cell
#one > list-view > list-cell
#one > list-view.list-cell
#one .list-view .list-cell
#one.list-cell
#one > list-cell
#one .list-cell
#one > .list-cell
```

Nothing works.

Now this getting a waste of time. Is CSS working in JavaFX or not? I do not want to use code to style elements.

Comment: The correct selector is `#one .list-cell`. This works fine for me. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: When you write `id="#one"`, you are doing this by calling `listView.setId("one");`, right? Not `listView.setId("#one")` (which is incorrect, obviously)? Again, it really helps if you post the code you are using.

Comment: @James_D I am defining it in the xml structure file

Comment: Please post code. No-one can help you figure out what you are doing wrong otherwise.

Comment: Hello all, it seems #<id> SPACE .<class> worked! thanks

Comment: So why did you state in your question that it didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors in the external CSS file for JavaFX follow the same structural rules as for CSS in HTML.

Basically:

```
#name
```

selects any node with the id `name`

```
.name
```

selects any node with CSS class `name`

Two selectors concatenated without a space select any single node which matches *both* selectors, so

```
#one.list-cell
```

would only select a node if it had an id of `one` and had the CSS class `list-cell`, etc.

```
selector1 > selector2
```

selects a node that matches `selector2` that is a *direct child* of a node that matches `selector1`, so

```
#one > .list-cell
```

selects any node with CSS class `list-cell` which is a direct child of a node with an id of `one`.

Finally,

```
selector1 selector2
```

selects any node matching `selector2` which is a *descendant* of a node matching `selector1`, so

```
#one .list-cell
```

selects any node with CSS class `list-cell` which is a descendent (direct or not) of a node with id `one`.

Referring to the [JavaFX CSS documentation for `ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#listview), you can see that a `ListView` has `ListCell`s as non-direct descendants. To be precise, it has a child with CSS class `virtual-flow`, which in turn has a child with CSS class `clipped-container`, which has `ListCell` children, which have all of the following CSS classes: `cell`, `indexed-cell`, and `list-cell`.

Consequently, if your `ListView` has an id `one`, then you can select the cells with

```
#one .list-cell
```

or

```
#one > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .list-cell
```

(the latter will potentially perform better, as the CSS engine doesn't have to search arbitrarily through the scene graph hierarchy; however the first version will be adequate for almost every use case).

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultipleListViewStyleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> firstList = new ListView<>();
        ListView<String> secondList = new ListView<>();

        firstList.setId("one");
        secondList.setId("two");

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).mapToObj(i -> "Item "+i).forEach(s -> {
            firstList.getItems().add(s);
            secondList.getItems().add(s);
        });

        HBox root = new HBox(10, firstList, secondList);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("multiple-list-view-style-test.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

multiple-list-view-style-test.css:

```
#one .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: rgba(16, 24, 49, 0.8);
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

#two .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: blue ;
}
```